# Normal basis of an extension of degree 4 over its prime field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I want to construct a normal basis of $\mathbb{F}_{p^4}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is an odd prime. Is there any particular method to do it?

Comment: If $p\equiv\pm2\pmod5$, it follows easily that a primitive fifth root of unity $\zeta_5$ generates $\Bbb{F}_p(\zeta_5)=\Bbb{F}_{p^4}$. Meaning that the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_5(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$. But, the other roots of $\Phi_5(x)$ are, in addition to being the Frobenius conjugates of $\zeta_5$ also its lowest powers $\zeta_5^j, j=1,2,3,4$. So if there were a linear dependency relation involving these fifth roots of unity, there would also be a lower degree polynomial with $\zeta_5$ as a root. Therefore $\zeta_5$ generates a normal basis.

Comment: The above method, while very efficient when it applies, is a bit ad hoc. They do apply similar tricks when looking for an efficient normal basis for a large finite field (in crypto).

Comment: Is there any similar kind of polynomial for the case $p\equiv\pm1(mod 5)$

Comment: I don't know of one. The generalization of that construction is the following. Let $q$ be a prime such that A) $q\equiv1\pmod4$, B) $p$ is a primitive root modulo $q$. Then the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_q(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$. Its zeros form a normal basis of $K=\Bbb{F}_{p^{q-1}}$ by the above argument. If $\alpha$ is one of those zeros (=roots of unity of order $q$), then the trace of $\alpha$ down to the subfield $\Bbb{F}_{p^4}\subseteq K$ generates a normal basis of $\Bbb{F}_{p^4}$. As $(q-1)/4$ grows, this gradually loses its appeal.

Answer (score 0):

You have the chain $\Bbb F_p\subset\Bbb F_{p^2}\subset\Bbb F_{p^4}$. In particular, any one, say $\alpha$, of the $p^4-p^2$ elements not in the quadratic extension will have four conjugates. Then $\{\alpha,\alpha^p,\alpha^{p^2},\alpha^{p^3}\}$ is your normal basis, since the Galois group is always generated by Frobenius.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not sufficient. The first counterexample that occurs to me comes when $p=2$. The polynomial $f(x)=x^4+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_2$, so if $\alpha$ is one of its zeros, then $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{16}\setminus\Bbb{F}_4$. But, the cubic term of $f(x)$ vanishes, so the trace of $\alpha$ is zero. In other words,
$$\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^4+\alpha^8=0$$
implying that this set of conjugates is linearly dependent over the prime field.

Comment: More generally, if $g(\tau)=\sum_i g_i\tau^i$ is any *proper* factor $\tau^4-1$ in $\Bbb{F}_p[\tau]$ we need to make sure that $g(F)$ does not annihilate $\alpha$ ($F$= Frobenius). Equivalently, we need to make sure that $\sum_ig_i\alpha^{p^i}\neq0$. Your answer only does this for the factor $g(\tau)=\tau^2-1$, but there may be other relevant polynomials $g(\tau)$. There is always $g(\tau)=\tau^2+1$, and, depending on $p$, possible other factors of $\tau^4-1$.